# pygame and keyboard events

Tags: pygame, keyboard-events

Using python3.4 on Mac OSX 10.10.3 with Pygame 1.9.2 & SDL 1.2.
Keyboard events are not being caught in the event loop while Mouse events are being seen. The Key strokes are unhelpfully being passed through to the terminal. 
Sample code:

```
    import pygame, sys
    from pygame.locals import *

    pygame.init()
    display = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

    while True:
    #wait for a single event from the queue
         pygame.event.pump()
         events = pygame.event.get()
         for event in events:
             if event.type == QUIT:
                 print('quitting')
                 pygame.quit()
                 sys.exit()
             else:
                 if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                     if event.key == K_LEFT:
                         print ("LEFT")
                     if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                         print ("RIGHT")
                     else:
                        print (event.key)
                 if event.type == KEYUP:
                     print('KEYUP')
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                print('got MOUSEBUTTONDOWN')
```

Any help would be appreciated. Answers to similar previous questions have not solved my problem.

Comment: _"Answers to similar previous questions have not solved my problem."_ - How so? What exactly didn't you understand from the other post?

Comment: This code works for me (on Linux). But you have to know that system sends key/mouse events to Pygame only if its window has focus. If you have focus on terminal then system sends keys directly to terminal. Maybe this is your problem - if you focus on other windows or hide PyGame window then system doesn't send key event to PyGame - and you can do nothing with this.

Answer (score 0):

Can't mark it as duplicate at the moment, but your context match [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45411542/1014321).

Short story : Use `python3 -m venv` instead of `virtualenv`.