# Pygame only detects mouse events, does not detect KEYDOWN events

Tags: python, pygame

I have written the following simple program which should print out all events detected by `pygame.event.get()`.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

display = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
pygame.init()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print(event)
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

But when I run this I only have mouse events, and a KEYDOWN and KEYUP event when I hit caps-lock twice, being printed in terminal. When I use any other keys they only print to terminal as if I was writing in the terminal window.

```
<Event(4-MouseMotion {'pos': (102, 15), 'buttons': (0, 0, 0),
 'rel': (-197, -284)})>
<Event(2-KeyDown {'unicode': '', 'scancode': 0, 'key': 301, 'm
 od': 8192})>
<Event(3-KeyUp {'key': 301, 'scancode': 0, 'mod': 0})>
wasd
```

I am using Mac OSX 10.12.1, python 3.5.2, and pygame 1.9.4.dev0.

I assume I'm missing something straight forward, but I found nothing similar online. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your code works for me with Python 3.5.2 and Pygame 1.9.3. Arrow keys, WASD, everything. Might be some bug introduced in 1.9.4dev0, but i doubt it. Seems like a window focus issue to me. What operating system and window manager are you on?

Comment: I'm on the current OSX, I'll downgrade to that version and see if it helps. Thanks.

Comment: I'm on Linux, might be difference in that. I'd try it with your version, but it's not on PyPI nor their Bitbucket. Where do I get `1.9.4.dev0`?

Comment: Nope, I've uninstalled, then installed pygame 1.9.3, and I am encountering the same issue. I find it odd that the caps-lock is detected.

Comment: I got 1.9.4.dev0 from the pygame website. But, for this install I used pip.

Comment: Found something. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718897/mac-os-x-pygame-input-goes-to-terminal-instead-of-python and this: https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issues/203/window-does-not-get-focus-on-os-x-with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone still struggling with this, the issue is documented here on git and is fixed.
https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/203

Just uninstall pygame from your venv, then install below version.

```
pip install -U https://github.com/pygame/pygame/archive/master.zip
```

Just tried this and can finally use key events in pygame.

Answer (score 3):

If you're working in a virtualenv, don't use the `virtualenv` command.

Use `python3 -m venv`.

Then install pygame (*e.g.* `pip3 install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame`).

See [this thread](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issues/203/window-does-not-get-focus-on-os-x-with#comment-32656108) for more details on this issue.

Comment: After searching around for about an hour, this was the exact problem! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Firstly i doubt you are but pygame only registers inputs when your focused on the pygame screen so there's that. I don't have a direct answer to your question so sorry but i do have my solution or work around to it. Because i dislike the normal event system i use pygame.key.get_pressed() (https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) just because i think it looks better and more readable. This is probably just a bad habit of mine though sooo.....