# Key inputs not working with Pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, sublimetext3, anaconda

I've been looking all over for an answer on this and I just can't seem to find it.

This issue I'm having is that when using Sublime Text 3 for writing a simple pygame script I can't get it to respond to key inputs. Whenever I push a key (the arrow keys specifically) this only gets registered in the editor and not the game window. Mouse inputs are registered though which makes it even more weird.

Is there any advice?

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('A bit Racey')

black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
crashed = False
carImg = pygame.image.load('racecar.png')
x = (display_width * 0.45)
y = (display_height * 0.8)


def car(x, y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg, (x, y))


x_change = 0
car_speed = 0

while not crashed:
    #print(pygame.event.get_grab())
    #pygame.event.set_grab(1)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            print("Hello")
            crashed = True
        ############################
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = -5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 5
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 0
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            print("hello my baby")
        ######################
    ##
    x += x_change
    gameDisplay.fill(black)
    car(x, y)
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Using python2.7 and pygame 1.9.3 (instead of python3.5 and pygame 1.9.4.dev0) did the trick for me.
These discussions may help: [bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issues/203/](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issues/203/window-does-not-get-focus-on-os-x-with) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512141/pygame-only-detects-mouse-events-does-not-detect-keydown-events?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Answer (score 0):

```
if event.type == KEYDOWN:
     if event.key == K_LEFT:
          x_change = -5
     elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
          x_change = 5
elif event.type == KEYUP:
     if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_RIGHT:
          x_change = 0
elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
     print("hello my baby")
```

I think The changes I made to your code will fix the problems you were having. Let me know if it works out.

Edit: In all my pygame script I include : "from pygame.locals import *" to my import list so that I don't to type pygame in front of everything. That should solve the error you had with my script.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. It crashes directly with the error message that "KEYDOWN" is undefined. But thank you anyway for the help.

Comment: Well that sucks, works perfectly fine on python 2.79. Sorry about that.